# How to fix npm installation CXX=clang++ --unsafe-perm

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, yarnpkg, macos-mojave

On an OSX machine - currently running Mojave - and I have a node and npm installation (or maybe more than one) where `-i` `install` can predictably not run unless `CXX=clang++` is prefixed to the npm or npx command, and `--unsafe-perm` is suffixed to the command, and sometimes `sudo` is a further prefix

pretty much every instruction that should be as simple as `npm install <package>` turns into `sudo CXX=clang++ npm install <package> --unsafe-perm` and everything I've read suggests this is a last resort and is conceptually unsafe

Its a deep rabbit hole to understanding how I got to this point, but at this point I have many notes that remind me to do this. I've upgraded npm and node multiple times, as they evolve very quickly, I don't think their specific versions are important here, but instead an OSX nuance that I'm not convinced is actually relevant, or hope isn't really relevant.

also I have a hunch that yarn is a part of the problem, or maybe its because of some old installation instructions for npm or node? beats me!

but not really sure how to start, but I saw similar questions on stackoverflow, but not specifically how to fix this

I want to get back to the place where simply copying and pasting npm install instructions from readme's actually works without any other jerry rigging

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what it happening on your system. However, I prefer to install `node.js` in my `$HOME`

```
> mkdir -p ~/opt/usr/local/node
> cd ~/opt/usr/local/node
> curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.0/node-v12.16.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
> tar zxf node-v12.16.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
> export PATH=$HOME/opt/usr/local/node/node-v12.16.0-darwin-x64/bin:${PATH}
```

and then, all `node.js` related activities are happening in my `$HOME`. This way I can avoid all the `sudo`, etc. stuff. I haven't (at least so far) noticed any major issues with this approach.